# Data overlapping while buffering message stream from Bluetooth

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to process JPS (Javad GREIS) live data stream from Bluetooth Serial. Here is the description about the stream.

- Stream Host sends data in various lengths but Plugin.BLE only caches 20 bytes (max) long packets.
- Each packet may contain part of a message, single message or multiple messages.
- Packets never padded with zeroes.
- Each message starts with header consists of 2 letter message identifier,3 letter message length in hex, leads with actual message and ends with 0x0A.

A message looks like this :`~~005XXXXX\n`

- "~~": Message Type,
- "005": Message Length,
- "X" represents actual message.

And packet may look like `"X\n~~005XXXXX\nSE001X\n"`. To process stream in real time, my app has to be in sync with message stream.
Problem is Bluetooth ValueUpdated event. It doesn't wait for `GREIS.Parse()` method to end before firing up the next event. `buffer.AddRange()` writes over old data. Due to this error, buffer looks like this `~~005XXSE002XX\n`. But it should be `~~005XXXXX\nSE002XX\n`.

Is there any way to hold the events or cache incoming data while Parser does it's job without losing any data or packet order?

```
    //GREIS.Parse
    public static string Parse(byte[] data)
    {     
        if (!sync)
        {
            if (isSync(data))
            {
                Wait = false;
                int MessageLength = decode_length("" + (char)data[2] + (char)data[3] + (char)data[4]);
                if (MessageLength != 0 && MessageLength < 8192)
                {
                    buffer.AddRange(data);
                    return Process();
                }
                else
                    return "Length Error";

            }
            else
                return "Not SYNC!";
        }
        
        buffer.AddRange(data);
        return Process();            
    }
```

Bluetooth ValueUpdated event handler:

```
   private async void OnReceiveGREIS_ValueUpdated(object sender, Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.EventArgs.CharacteristicUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        string res = "";

        res = GREIS.Parse(e.Characteristic.Value);
        await Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
        {
            Output.Text = res;
        });

    }
```

Comment: You could use semaphores.  Or you could just add each message to a  `Queue<string>` as you receive it, and then have a separate function process each message as it's added

Comment: While adding to Queue, another event fires up and main thread focuses on new event.  Data won't be in order anymore. And i think you meant Queue<byte> right @Jason?

Comment: then use semaphores, which is probably the proper way to handle this

Comment: If ValueUpdated did **only** `queue.Enqueue(e.Characteristic.Value);` (or maybe need to copy that value to store in queue), then how would it get out of order? Everything else could be done by a dequeue thread.

Comment: Recently tested on iOS and it works ok. In Android, packets always getting out of order. I tested other BLE Serial apps in Android to ensure no hardware related issue causes this problem. And hardware seems to be ok too. I think Plugin.BLE not working properly on Android. I will update the question if anything comes up.